# wkhtmltopdf creating empty pdf

Tags: asp.net, pdf, wkhtmltopdf, pdf-conversion

I am using `wkhtmltopdf`to convert HTML page to PDF in ASP.NET. The following is my coding

```
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.StartInfo.FileName = Server.MapPath("~/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf.exe");
    string arguments = "\"" + "http://localhost:51528/settings/InvoiceStatementPrint.aspx?InvoiceID=48\"" + " " + Server.MapPath("~/settings/" + "InvoiceDetail_1.pdf");
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
    p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    p.Start();
    p.WaitForExit();
    p.Close();
    p.Dispose();
}
```

The URL creates proper page. But  `InvoiceDetail_1.pdf` generates black page PDF. Is there is any thing wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code, the problem will be with your input HTML.  Try running the tool standalone and you'll see the same results.

As an aside, [TuesPechkin](https://github.com/tuespetre/TuesPechkin) provides an easier way of calling wkhtmltopdf from .NET.